# How to prove that this function is delta function when t $\to$ 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, dirac-delta

Let's have function
$$
\tag 1 f(x, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i\pi t}}e^{i\frac{x}{t}}.
$$
How to prove that $(1)$ is delta-function when $t \to 0$?

I have tried to use "usual" properties of delta-function, 
$$
\int f(x, t)dx = 1, \quad f(0, t \to 0) = \infty , \quad f(x \neq 0, t \to 0) = 0,
$$
but there is the problem with the third identity: the function strongly oscillates instead of be zero. But peolpe say that $(1)$ becomes delta-function when $t$ goes to zero. So how to show that?

Addition.

Maybe it's good to make Fourier transformation of $f(x, t)$ and then to get that $\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} f(p, t) = 1$, which is the Fourier image of delta-function.

Comment: I assume you mean $t\to 0^+$ because of of the square root? In fact, you should specify which square root of $i$ you mean as well.

Comment: @AdamHughes : yes, $t \to 0^{+}$, and $\sqrt{i} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$.

Comment: Remember that the dirac $\delta$ is not a function, but a distribution, so what you need to show is that

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{\Bbb R}f(x,t)g(x)\,dx=g(0)$$ for every integrable function, $g$.

Comment: @AdamHughes : it seems to me that the distribution equality which you have wrote is the consequence of the identities which I have wrote. Am I right?